# libgdx ragdoll physics with animation

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, libgdx, blender

I'm in the planning stages of game dev. and am wondering whether or not to pick unity or Libgdx. I already know quite a bit of java, and I want to make a 2D sidescroller that uses ragdoll physics with animation. I have been looking pretty hard, but haven't found a good resource for this yet with Libgdx. It seems possible with Unity though. The resources I have found so far with Libgdx are :

- Rube
- Glee2d
- Spine
- Blender

So far with this it seems possible to make a level with a skeletal 2d animating sprite, but is it possible to apply ragdoll physics to this creation so, for example, if an enemy was shot it  would react like a ragdoll?
I appreciate any help!
Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You could clearly use libgdx for that.

You'd have to create the ragdoll as box2d bodies (which can be done with rube). For rendering the ragdoll, you could use the setUserData() methods in box2d to bind an actor to the body/fixture. After each simulation step you would update the actors and create the proper rendering.

You could then place the ragdoll somewhere and shoot it with some other box2d body, let's say a cannonball...

Comment: Would this work with animation though? What do you mean by simulation step? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well libgdx contains a box2d port. Box2d is a physics engine, where you will define a world and a set of static bodies (your ground), kinetic bodies (like moving platforms etc) and dynamic bodies (your ragdoll and the cannonball/bullet)... Within your render-loop you have to step the simulation, basically advance it a little bit. So your objects will move according to the forces and impulses acting on it.

And after this simulation step you would update the scene (the rendering) accordingly. There are tutorials on that in the libgdx wiki. It's quite easy :)

Comment: so this can be used with animation?

Comment: What do you mean with animation? If your ragdoll will get moved and transformed in a simulation step and you then update the images that render the different parts of the ragdoll (body, arms, head, ...), it will produce a smooth animation of that body flying around... I am not sure if I am understanding your question the right way...

Comment: Could I have the player running around and then have him get shot and react like a ragdoll is what i mean. Thanks,

Comment: @evident did you find the solution for this?